# dependencia firebase/app não encontrada

Tags: angular, firebase, npm

Ao usar o comando `ng serve` o mesmo retorna a seguinte mensagem .

> ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/fire" has missing
>   dependencies:
>    - firebase/app

já exclui o `node_modules` e o `package-lock.json` e rodei `npm install` novamente, mas não funcionou.

Comment: As perguntas não podem depender de links externos. o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) pode ajudar ao [edit] o post. Importante procurar fornecer um [mcve] ou uma descrição que mostre como reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esqueceu de colocar a dependência do próprio firebase.

```
npm i firebase
```

Aproveitando a oportunidade, você possui alguns erros na classe ***src\app\app.component.ts***

1. Falta adicionar um } no final do arquivo
2. A importação de **AngularFirestore** está errada, o correto é: `import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`